# Old archivelog files present on disk, but not in RMAN

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, rman, archive-log

I recently spotted 3 very old archivelog directories on disk that do not appear within RMAN.

```
[oracle@ORACLE01 archivelog]$ du -sh *
122M    2017_02_25
4.9G    2017_02_26
2.5G    2017_02_27
1.6G    2017_06_28
474M    2017_06_29
```

Within RMAN, archivelogs appear from the 28th June (as I would expect)

```
RMAN> list archivelog all;  (list truncated for brevity)
using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
List of Archived Log Copies for database with db_unique_name R2CI
=====================================================================

Key     Thrd Seq     S Low Time
------- ---- ------- - -------------------
30329   1    81000   A 28/06/2017 10:45:26
        Name: /u01/.../archivelog/2017_06_28/o1_mf_1_81000_do72c0ng_.arc

30330   1    81001   A 28/06/2017 10:48:00
        Name: /u01/.../archivelog/2017_06_28/o1_mf_1_81001_do73f110_.arc
```

If I run a crosscheck archivelog all, this picks up only the recent archivelog files that I expect to be there:

```
RMAN> crosscheck archivelog all;

allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=21 device type=DISK
validation succeeded for archived log
archived log file name=/u01/.../archivelog/2017_06_28/o1_mf_1_81000_do72c0ng_.arc RECID=30329 STAMP=947846881
validation succeeded for archived log
archived log file name=/u01/.../archivelog/2017_06_28/o1_mf_1_81001_do73f110_.arc RECID=30330 STAMP=947847970
validation succeeded for archived log
archived log file name=/u01/.../archivelog/2017_06_28/o1_mf_1_81002_do74pzcw_.arc RECID=30331 STAMP=947849313
validation succeeded for archived log
(list truncated for brevity)
```

A "list archivelog all" after this point does not show these old files.

Questions:

1. Where are these files likely to have have come/why weren't they
   eventually expired and deleted like the rest of the archivelogs?
2. Why does crosscheck archivelog all not detect them and add them
   back? is it because there is a 4 month gap between them and the next
   most recent files?
3. Is it safe to just delete these files off disk?

Thanks

Comment: What's your backup retention policy? as well as what value the `control_file_record_keep_time` parameter is set to?

Comment: Did you check this post? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171008/why-are-my-backups-using-so-much-space-ora-19804

Comment: @JSapkota - control_file_record_keep_time is currently set to 7, and retention policy is 'recovery window of 3 days'. No - I hadn't read that post as it didn't look relevant from the question title - reading it now thanks.

Comment: Do you have a full backup on disk of that time period which requires these archived logs?

Comment: no - oldest backup is from the 19th June. (archivelogs are from february). I see from your comment on that other post that the control_file_record_keep_time value is too small. I will increase this to (3 + 7 + 1) = 11 days

Comment: are the files in the   "output of crosscheck archivelog all"?

Comment: @miracle173 - no, I can't find see them in rman at all. 'crosscheck archivelog all' only reports files from the last day  (basically as far back as the archivelogs go, excluding these ones from february).  'list archivelog all' only shows the same files from the last day. Permissions on all folders/archivelogs are good afaics - all owned by oracle with rw perms

Comment: "Why does crosscheck archivelog all not detect them and add them back?"  Because that's not what crosscheck does.  Crosscheck reads the records of the archlogs that are recorded in the repository - the ones that rman reports. It reads a record from the repository, then checks to see if that file exists.  If not, the record is marked 'expired'.  If rman shows no sign of knowing of these files, I'd say it's safe to delete them.

Comment: @edstevens - thanks for that. I'll go ahead and delete them. If you want to reformat your question as an answer I'll accept it so anyone else looking knows this question has an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does crosscheck archivelog all not detect them and add them back?

Because that's not what `crosscheck` does. Crosscheck reads the records of the archlogs that are recorded in the repository - the ones that `rman` reports. It reads a record from the repository, then checks to see if that file exists. If not, the record is marked 'expired'. If `rman` shows no sign of knowing of these files, I'd say it's safe to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

> Where are these files likely to have have come/why weren't they
>   eventually expired and deleted like the rest of the archivelogs?

I would suspect that these files vanished from your repo because the following conditions were met: The files where not needed anymore to meet your recovery policy (rman policy) and they also exceeded the parameter controlfile_record_keep_time. At this point Oracle would overwrite the records in your controlfile. If you backup and delete archivelogs on daily terms, you should not have any "dead" archivelogs.

EdStevens already answered the other two questions...

Comment: ahhh. Yeah I do backup and delete daily, but conceivably there could have been a lapse for a few days when the control_file_record_keep_time parameter was set too low of a value. (increased now). Thanks!