# How do we recover archivelogs which are deleted by rman but on disk?

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

We have have rman which keeps only the current day backup.
In asm we have a directory in +RECO/db1/ARCHIVELOG/ which stores the archive logs for the last couples of months.
Our archivelog path is the following: +RECO/late

In RMAN we do not see the archive log for the previous days.

How can we recover the archive logs for the previous day?

Should we be moving the archivelogs from +RECO/db1/ARCHIVELOG/ to +RECO/late ?

Other:
[Old archivelog files present on disk, but not in RMAN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177559/old-archivelog-files-present-on-disk-but-not-in-rman)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
catalog start with '+RECO/db1/ARCHIVELOG/';
```

The above command in RMAN searches and catalogs files under `+RECO/db1/ARCHIVELOG/`. This creates the necessary entries in the controlfile pointing to those archivelogs after which RMAN should be able to use them.

You may need to increase the value of `control_file_record_keep_time` parameter to prevent these entries reused (overwritten) by new entries.